# whoami returns apache instead of root

Tags: php, apache, centos7, vhosts

I'm trying to serve an application from location `/usr/local/administer/`. There is a `index.php` file inside `/usr/local/administer/index.php` inside that `index.php` file is the following code

```
echo exec('whoami');
```

The result from the above code is `apache` however the result should be `root` as per my configuration in the `vhost` using [mod-ruid2](http://%20https://github.com/mind04/mod-ruid2)

***administer.conf***

The following is the configuration that I'm currently working with.

```
<Directory /usr/local/administer/web>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /usr/local/administer/
    ServerName administer.com
    ServerAlias www.administer.com
    RMode config
    RUidGid root root
    RGroups root
</VirtualHost>
```

Any suggestions or advise?

Comment: "Good"? Never, ever, run your web server with root permissions. Keep this setup, and make sure permissions are set correctly for the `apache` user instead.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans This is not real server. I'm just playing around with it.

Comment: I don't think user `root` will show up on `whoami` when running via PHP. How about this, create another user in the system and replace `root` in your .conf file to this new user.

Comment: @NavneilNaicker Awesome it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/740553/mike-pomax-kamermans) has mentioned in the comment that not to run any task via PHP with `root` user. You'll get into trouble. If you are logged-in as `root` and running `whoami` via PHP then `root` won't show up. I'm not sure why this is happening. A possible solution in my preference is:

1. Create another user
2. Replace root with the new username
3. Restart Apache